# matplotlib path linewidth connected to figure zoom

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Is it possible to tie the linewidth of a matplotlib path to the figure zoom/scale level?

I am drawing a map where the matplotlib path (with bezier curves) draws the road on the map. Upon zooming in I would like the width of the path to zoom in.

In attached script, the polygonal approximation can properly zoom, but the path (red line) cannot zoom (in width).

Is it possible to tie the linewidth to some scale transformation and redraw via callback ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

def main():
  ax = plt.subplot(111)
  verts = np.array([ (0., 0.), (0.5, .5), (1., 0.8), (0.8, 0.)])
  codes = np.array([Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4, Path.LINETO ])

  # Can this curve have zoomable width
  path = Path(verts, codes)
  patch = patches.PathPatch(path, fc='none', color='r', lw=4, zorder=3)
  ax.add_patch(patch)

  ax.plot(verts[:,0], verts[:,1], 'o--', lw=2, color='k', zorder=2)

  # these will be polygonal approx that will have proper zoom
  v=np.array([]).reshape((-1,2))
  c=[]
  for i in range(len(verts)-1):
    vtmp, ctmp = line2poly(verts[[i,i+1],:],0.03)
    v = np.vstack( (v,vtmp) )
    c = np.concatenate( (c,ctmp) )
  path_zoom = Path(v,c)
  patch_zoom =  patches.PathPatch(path_zoom, fc='r', ec='k', zorder=1, alpha=0.4)
  ax.add_patch(patch_zoom)

  ax.set_xlim(-0.1, 1.1)
  ax.set_ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
  plt.show()

def line2poly(line, width):
  dx,dy = np.hstack(np.diff(line,axis=0)).tolist()
  theta = np.arctan2(dy,dx)
  print(np.hstack(np.diff(line,axis=0)).tolist())
  print(np.degrees(theta))
  s = width/2 * np.sin(theta)
  c = width/2 * np.cos(theta)
  trans = np.array([(-s,c),(s,-c),(s,-c),(-s,c)])

  verts = line[[0,0,1,1],:]+trans
  verts = np.vstack((verts, verts[0,:]))
  codes = np.array([Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.LINETO, Path.CLOSEPOLY])
  return verts,codes

if __name__=='__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: `plt.quiver` does this somehow, but I'm not sure how to utilize that information :P

Comment: hmmm.... plt.quiver does not do this for me.

Comment: @askewchan - `quiver` does it because it uses polygons instead of paths (i.e. there's no stroke for the arrows, instead they're polygons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to do this in matplotlib, as the stroke width of a line cannot be directly tied to data coordinates.  (As you mentioned, you could connect a callback to the draw event and accomplish this. It would incur a large performance penalty, though.)

However, a quick workaround would be to use `shapely` to generate polygons by buffering your street paths.

As a quick example:

```
import shapely.geometry
import descartes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lines = ([(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)],
         [(0, 0), (1, 1)],
         [(0.5, 0.5), (1, 0.5)],
         )
lines = shapely.geometry.MultiLineString(lines)
# "0.05" is the _radius_ in data coords, so the width will be 0.1 units.
poly = lines.buffer(0.05)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patch = descartes.PolygonPatch(poly, fc='gray', ec='black')
ax.add_artist(patch)

# Rescale things to leave a bit of room around the edges...
ax.margins(0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you did want to take the callback route, you might do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    lines = ([(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)],
             [(0, 0), (1, 1)],
             [(0.5, 0.5), (1, 0.5)],
             )

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    artists = []
    for verts in lines:
        x, y = zip(*verts)
        line, = ax.plot(x, y)
        artists.append(line)

    scalar = StrokeScalar(artists, 0.1)
    ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', scalar)
    ax.callbacks.connect('ylim_changed', scalar)

    # Rescale things to leave a bit of room around the edges...
    ax.margins(0.05)

    plt.show()

class StrokeScalar(object):
    def __init__(self, artists, width):
        self.width = width
        self.artists = artists
        # Assume there's only one axes and one figure, for the moment...
        self.ax = artists[0].axes
        self.fig = self.ax.figure

    def __call__(self, event):
        """Intended to be connected to a draw event callback."""
        for artist in self.artists:
            artist.set_linewidth(self.stroke_width)

    @property
    def stroke_width(self):
        positions = [[0, 0], [self.width, self.width]]
        to_inches = self.fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted().transform
        pixels = self.ax.transData.transform(positions)
        points = to_inches(pixels) * 72
        return points.ptp(axis=0).mean() # Not quite correct...

main()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to draw bezier curves in shapely and dilate/buffer them?

Comment: @waqy - No, `shapely` treats lines as linear segments. You'd have to approximate them.   I updated my answer with a callback-based way to do it using only matplotlib (it's exactly correct unless the aspect ratio is set to 1).

Comment: Thanks. Your callback-based scheme works perfectly (for curves and text too.)

Comment: Glad it helped! There are some oddities with it in certain cases that I can't quite figure out.  Also, in my previous comment, I meant to say "it's _not_ exactly correct unless the aspect ratio is set to 1". On a brighter note, the "large performance penalty" I mentioned turns out to be completely insignificant.  That's what I get for guessing before I try it!